# If statement in javascript not identifying the values

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The function should, when called, change the value of the isSize variable to 80 if it is currently 50 and to 50 if it’s currently 80. It also includes the call the setSize
function after it along with the parameter.

```
function changeSize (Size){ 

var isSize = Size;

if(isSize == 80){ 

  this.isSize == 50; 
}   

else if (isSize == 50){ 

  this.isSize == 80;    
}   

else {      
  return isSize;    
}   

  setSize(isSize);

    }
```

I am not recieving a result. any help will do! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to use "switch" instead of using "if" :

```
function changeSize (Size){ 

  var isSize = parseInt(Size);

  switch(isSize ){
     case 80: 
       isSize = 50;
       break; 
     case 50:
       isSize = 80;    
       break;
     default: 
       return isSize;    
  }   

  setSize(isSize);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `=` instead of `==`, and as Mehmood mentioned, change `this.isSize` to `isSize`

```
function changeSize(Size) {

    var isSize = Size;

    if (isSize == 80) {

        isSize = 50;

    } else if (isSize == 50) {

        isSize = 80;

    } else {

        return isSize;
    }

    setSize(isSize);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
changeSize(50);
function changeSize (Size){ 

var isSize = Size;

if(isSize == 80){ 

  isSize = 50; 
}   

else if (isSize == 50){ 

  isSize = 80;    
}   

else {      
  return isSize;    
}   

  setSize(isSize);

    }

function setSize(Size){
    alert("New Size: "+Size);
}
```

You are making two mistakes in your coding.

[**Here is demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2y8hve9j/)

Remove `this.` and  Replace `==` to `=`  :

```
this.isSize == 80;
```